# What would happen if most the fat in your body was rapidly converted into energy in 2 minutes?

Tags: fat-metabolism, energy

It all started out as an argument I had with my friend.He said that "it would be the equivalent of catching a fire and burning"

But all I thought would happen is that you would now be very hyper because you have a lot of energy in you body.

Please scientific answers only.

I also happen to be in the 11th grade and I dont do bio, but I knew this would be the best place to post the question.Please dont use scientific concepts I would not understand.

You guys are probably going to ask me to give an example of a way through which it might happen. So here is one way I have come up with:
Lets say the AMPK protein malfunctions and causes all the cells to release all this energy.

Comment: I would love to read an "xkcd what if" answer to that question

Answer (score 4):

It depends, but you're going to die.

Specifically, it depends on how fat you are. Even [Andreas Munzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_M%C3%BCnzer) is going to die. At only 3% body fat, burning all his fat (9kcal/g) would "only" increase his internal body temperature by 270 degrees C. Factoring in the energy required to boil off his body moisture and adding in body heat leaves Andreas at  ~200 C or so (pretty unevenly distributed) minus whatever heat he could give off through his skin in two minutes. He's definitely dead, but probably not on fire. The flash point of animal fat oil is [about 300 C](http://cameochemicals.noaa.gov/chris/TLO.pdf), so most of his body probably isn't going to be hot enough to burn on its own. There will probably be some smoking, though.

The average body fat percentage is more like 22%(for males), and the numbers there are unequivocal. That person is going to catch on fire, as their body temperature is going to go up about ~1800 C after boiling off all the water. That's enough to melt your titanium hip implants.

In short: you'll die pretty quickly, and then you might catch on fire before your two minutes are up, unless you're Andreas Munzer or another professional bodybuilder.